# How do I set up a control mechanism to find repeated letters?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, controls

I'm a newbie C programmer. I want to print repeated letters in string. First of all, user enters letters and getchar() collects and places them in an array. After that this array should be scanned and program should be print "character repeated x times." For ex: A is repeated 5 times. Here is my source code and I wrote this code but I have some problems. I want to if the number of repeats of a letter is printed, it should not be printed again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t message[100];
    wint_t ch;
    int i = 0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    wprintf(L"Enter your message: ");

    while ((ch = getwchar()) != '\n')
    {
        message[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }



    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        int repeated = 1;
        for (int k = j + 1; k < i; k++)
        {
            if (message[j] == message[k])
                repeated++;
        }
        wprintf(L"%lc is repeated %d times.\n", message[j], repeated);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

True output should be :

```
a is repeated 5 times.
b is repeated 5 times.
c is repeated 5 times.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Index an int[256] array with the char.

Comment: With a match `(message[j] == message[k])`, set `message[k] = '\n'` - and do not add up when `message[j] == '\n')`.  Other approach would swap `message[k]` with the last on the list and make the list 1 shorter.  Many ways.

Comment: @MartinJames the classic `int count[256]` is problematic if OP truly needs to handle `wchar_t`, especially if it is 4-byte.

Comment: root_roxox: Text says "user enters letters and getchar() collects " and code has `getwchar()`.  Is this a `char` problem or a `wchar_t` one?  Do you need to handle non-ASCII chracters?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica oops!  I missed the wchar include:(  Yes, of course you are right, an int array[MAX_UINT] would be a problem, yes:)

Comment: Thanks for all but I didn't  understand it. Can u add what I need to add for this in my code and send it to me ?

Comment: @root_roxox you want the code but not the understanding.  Hmmm.

Comment: @root_roxox I have updated my answer with a more detailed explanation - hope it will help you understand the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to mark the characters that you have alreay counted so that you can avoid counting the character again.

You can do that by using the first character as a mark that means "Already counted so skip this character". You do that by changing characters that are counted to be equal the first character. When you move through the string, you simply skip characters that equals the first character.

Example:

Let's say the text i "HelloHey" then it goes like:

```
1. iteration "HelloHey" -> "HelloHey" and print "H 2 times"
2. iteration "HelloHey" -> "HelloHHy" and print "e 2 times" (second e replaced by H)
3. iteration "HelloHHy" -> "HelHoHHy" and print "l 2 times" (second l replaced by H) 
4. iteration skip because of an 'H' in position 4 of "HelHoHHy"
5. iteration "HelHoHHy" -> "HelHoHHy" and print "o 1 time" 
6. iteration skip because of an 'H' in position 6 of "HelHoHHy"
7. iteration skip because of an 'H' in position 7 of "HelHoHHy"
8. iteration "HelHoHHy" -> "HelHoHHy" and print "y 1 time"
```

The code could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
    wchar_t text[] = L"Hello world";
    wchar_t* p = text + 1;
    unsigned i = 1;

    // Unconditional loop to count first letter
    while(*p)
    {
        if (*p == text[0])
        {
            ++i;
        }
        ++p;
    }
    printf("[%lc] seen %u times\n", text[0], i);

    // Loop the remaining string
    p = text + 1;
    while(*p)
    {
        // Only count if current letter differs from first letter
        if (*p != text[0])
        {
            // New character - count its occurence
            wchar_t* t = p + 1;
            unsigned i = 1;
            while (*t) 
            {
                if (*p == *t) 
                {
                    ++i; 
                    *t = text[0];   // Mark letter as counted
                }
                ++t;
            }
            printf("[%lc] seen %u times\n", *p, i);
        }
        ++p;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[H] seen 1 times
[e] seen 1 times
[l] seen 3 times
[o] seen 2 times
[ ] seen 1 times
[w] seen 1 times
[r] seen 1 times
[d] seen 1 times
```

Comment: OP is looking to avoid repeating `[l] seen 3 times`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica hmm... maybe.. answer updated